# mpld3 interactive legend does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, python, internet-explorer, d3.js, mpld3

I am using the mpld3 library in python and I have notice that on internet explorer the interactive legend plugins does not work.

I've also notice that on the mpld3 web site, the example of interactive legend also does not work in IE.

So i'm kind of stuck here... any help ?[you can see on that image that the interactive legend does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbdIg.png)

I'll also put the mpld3 interactive plugins link here: https://mpld3.github.io/examples/interactive_legend.html

Comment: It will be hard for people to help you without any code in your question. What research have you done so far? Is this feature supported in the version of IE you are trying? Consider reading this and editing your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the code is in the link and i think that IE might not supported this feature, but it's not specified in the documentation. That's why i'm asking here

Comment: Actually it is mentioned in the code that is generated for the page.
`console.log(type + " is not yet supported"); `, not to mention that it doesn't help either. 

Maybe you need to log the `type` and try to play with that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of code in mpld3/plugins.py causing IE incompatibility:

- line 582 `var type = d.mpld3_elements[i].constructor.name`
- line 614 `var type = d.mpld3_elements[0].constructor.name`

replace them with:

- `var type = d.mpld3_elements[i].constructor.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)[1];`
- `var type = d.mpld3_elements[0].constructor.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)[1];`

Taken from https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/191